# How to upgrade OpenSSL in Linux without using make

Tags: linux, openssl, gentoo, nao-robot

I'm using a Robot that is running on a customized version of Gentoo and `make` is not available in it. I want to upgrade the Robot's OpenSSL version since it's super outdated but all the upgrade method that I found so far requires me to use `make` command. Is there any method that doesn't require `make`?

Note that, the Robot came with a VM that mirrored the Robot software and hardware capabilities. The `make` command is available in the VM. Is it possible if I do the upgrading in the VM and transfer the files to the Robot?

Comment: what kind of robot is this?

Comment: @LucasRamage It's a NAO Robot from Softbank Robotics

Answer (score 1):

You can cross compile it on your system and then just replace the binaries on the robot.

Comment: How to find where the system compile the ssl (something like installation folder)? or is it just the openssl binary in /usr/bin?

Comment: When you cross compile the binary will be in the folder you cross compiled. replace binary found on `whereis openssl` with the new binary.

Comment: That isn't a good idea since the binaries are most likely dynamically linked; that could really mess up your system.

Comment: Gentoo has several ROOT options for output, you can compile to a root that contains the robots OS and update SSL that way.  Other options include creating a binary package for dist and then extracting it on the robots system.